# Angular js way to upload image to google cloud storage using signed urls

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to create a meanjs framework app where the user can upload images files to a private bucket on google cloud storage.

I would like to take the approach where the authentication info is supplied by the node js server to the client web page so that the client web page can send the image directly to GCS without passing it through my nodesj web server using signed URLs.

Googling around, I found a similar example here

https://github.com/sfarthin/nodejs-google-cloud-storage

I tried the sample app and it works as advertised - I can write to a bucket i created in my private repo using my credentials key file. - Perfect.

The only problem is that in this sample app, the author uses an ejs file as the front end using some kind of multipart form data in and ejs file. I want to have all the front end in angular, but I am not sure how to do it.

Here is a snippet of the front end form from the github site that I know works, which i want to reimplement in angular (not sure how to do it):

```
<h4>Choose a file, click upload, then after the upload finishes you may view it by clicking the link below. A file will be uploaded with the key "<%=fields.key%>".</h4>
<form action="https://<%=fields.bucket%>.storage.googleapis.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<%=fields.key%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="<%=fields.bucket%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="<%=fields.GoogleAccessId%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<%=fields.policy%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<%=fields.signature%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="<%=fields['Content-Type']%>">

    <input name="file" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<br />

<a href="https://<%=fields.bucket%>.storage.googleapis.com/<%=fields.key%>" target="_new">View https://<%=fields.bucket%>.storage.googleapis.com/<%=fields.key%></a>
```

So far, I created an angular client view as follows:

```
 <section data-ng-controller="inventoryPhotoMgrController" data-ng-init="findOne()">
<div class="page-header">

    <h1 data-ng-bind="inventoryItem.itemTitle">{{inventoryItem.itemTitle}}</h1>
    <h2>Inventory Item Photos</h2>
</div>
<h4>Main Photo:</h4>
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
```

And here are the important parts on my angular controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is '+file.name);

        console.dir(file);
        var storageImageName=$scope.inventoryItem.itemNumber+'-'+file.name;
        console.log('storageImageName='+storageImageName);
        // get the key authorization data from node server
        $http.get('/inventoryStore/'+storageImageName)
        .success(function (response) {
            var fields= response;
            console.log('fields=');
            console.dir(fields);
            $scope.storePhoto(fields,file);

        }).error(function (response) {
            $scope.error = response.message;
        });
```

And here too:

```
enter code $scope.storePhoto=function(fields,file){
        var url='https://'+fields.bucket+'.storage.googleapis.com';


        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
        form.setAttribute('action', url);
        form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        form._submit_function_ = form.submit;


        var keyField = document.createElement('input');
        keyField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        keyField.setAttribute('name', 'key');
        keyField.setAttribute('value', fields.key);
        form.appendChild(keyField);

        var bucketField = document.createElement('input');
        bucketField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        bucketField.setAttribute('name', 'bucket');
        bucketField.setAttribute('value', fields.bucket);
        form.appendChild(bucketField);

        var gaidField = document.createElement('input');
        gaidField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        gaidField.setAttribute('name', 'GoogleAccessId');
        gaidField.setAttribute('value', fields.GoogleAccessId);
        form.appendChild(gaidField);

        var polField = document.createElement('input');
        polField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        polField.setAttribute('name', 'policy');
        polField.setAttribute('value', fields.policy);
        form.appendChild(polField);

        var sigField = document.createElement('input');
        sigField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        sigField.setAttribute('name', 'signature');
        sigField.setAttribute('value', fields.signature);
        form.appendChild(sigField);

        var ctField = document.createElement('input');
        ctField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        ctField.setAttribute('name', 'Content-Type');
        ctField.setAttribute('value', fields['Content-Type']);
        form.appendChild(ctField);

        var fField = document.createElement('input');

        fField.setAttribute('name', 'file');
        fField.setAttribute('value', file);
        form.appendChild(fField);



        form._submit_function_();
    };
```

When I hit the upload me button, a file gets stored in my bucket with the correct name, so I know my keys are good and cors is good, but I see on the google developers console that the size is just 13 bytes and I cant view the image file. If i click the link it just says '[object File]'

I think I am not formatting my form post to google correctly. Perhaps the fField element is not correct.

Like I said, the githib sample app works fine, but I don’t know enough about angular/javascript to understand how to convert the form ejs to send the equivalent in js within an angular controller.

Any advice?  Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: can you make it work? I am interested in this also.